# Delete Parse PFUser Account

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I have an app(written in Swift) that uses Parse and allows a User to create an account. I want the user to have the option to delete their account but can't seem to figure it out and not sure what I'm doing wrong. I want the user to have to verify their email and password for this to occur. Once they've deleted their account, an alert pops up and then once the user dismisses the alert it takes them back to the log in screen and out of the app.

This is what I've tried:

```
   @IBAction func deleteAccount(sender: AnyObject) {

 if PFUser.currentUser()?.username == emailAddressTextField.text && PFUser.currentUser()?.password == passwordTextFieldOne.text && PFUser.currentUser()?.password == passwordTextFieldTwo.text {

 PFUser.currentUser()?.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if success {

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Success!", message: "Now Please Login", preferredStyle: .Alert)

            let enterAppAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login")
                    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            })

                alertController.addAction(enterAppAction)

                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {

            print(error)
            self.displayAlert("Account deletion failed", message: "Please try again", actionTitle: "OK")

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No I think that's not reading the PFUser.currentUser password because when I printed it out it prints nil. Which makes sense because Parse protects their passwords. I just got it to work so the user can delete their count but it does NOT require any e-mail or password verification. They just hit a button and it deletes the account. I'd prefer to have verification.

Comment: Can you try to do something like query.wherekey(email = PFUser.currentUser().email) and after that do a delete? I don't remeber the correcxt syntax of the query.wherekey..

Answer (score 0):

You can make a cloud function to verify that the user correctly entered their current password and have it return success/error to iOS, at which point you can delete the account (provided the successful completion of the password check). Here's a [relevant Parse forum post](https://www.parse.com/questions/checking-a-user-password).

From the referenced post:

```
Parse.Cloud.define(FUNCTION_PASSWORD_CHECK, function(request, response) 
{
    var password = request.params.password;

    Parse.User.logIn(request.user.getUsername(), password, {
        success: function(results) 
        {   
            response.success(true);
        },
        error: function() {
            response.success(false);
        }
    });
});
```

Note: you can do a similar login function on iOS, but that may mess with the PFUser.currentUser() if the user incorrectly enters their password (I'm not sure on that). Also, the referenced function uses the request.user, which is advised (i.e., not passing the user as a param as well), so that it only works for users with sessions.

Comment: Thanks this seems like the right path to go down. I haven't used Parse cloud functions before but I'm going to learn it. This seems to lead me down the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial if-statement:

```
if PFUser.currentUser()?.username == emailAddressTextField.text && PFUser.currentUser()?.password == passwordTextFieldOne.text && PFUser.currentUser()?.password == passwordTextFieldTwo.text
```

The statement `PFUser.currentUser()?.password` will return nil as parse does not make a users password accessible to you. Therefore, you won't be able to compare the user's password with the text entered into the textfield.

To check if the user has in fact entered a password that matches an existing password:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(PFUser.currentUser(), password:passwordTextFieldOne.text!) {
    (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if user != nil {
         //continue with delete function   
    } else {
        //Display error
    }
}
```